# DNS intranet setup not working

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, dns, dd-wrt

I'm running into an issue with a BIND9 DNS setup on my home server.

When I use `nslookup` and `dig` from SSH on the home server (192.168.1.20) I get results back, and `curl` also returns webpages where applicable, so the home server does see my zone configs properly.

However, when I access the intranet from a local client (192.168.1.30, my Windows PC), I get `can't connect to the server` via Firefox, `the remote name could not be resolved` via curl, and `*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for REDACTED` via nslookup. The DNS resolution should be getting properly forwarded by the router (192.168.1.1), but apparently this isn't working or some other issue is at play since the home server works fine.

**Netgear Router** DD-WRT (192.168.1.1):

```
RouterName: REDACTED
HostName:   REDACTED (Same as RouterName)

LocalIP:    192.168.1.1
SubnetMask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway:    0.0.0.0
LocalDNS:   192.168.1.20 (is this correct? should this be 0.0.0.0?)

StaticDNS1: 192.168.1.20 
StaticDNS2: 1.1.1.1 
StaticDNS3: 1.0.0.1
WINS:       0.0.0.0
DnsMasqDHCP:   Enabled
DnsMasqDNS:    Enabled
DnsMasqAuth:   Enabled
ForceDNSRedir: Disabled
```

For DHCP Srv:

```
UsedDomain: LAN & WLAN
LANDomain: inet (*.REDACTED.inet is BIND9 intranet zone. could this be interfering?)
```

For DnsMasq Srv:

```
DNSMasq:        Enabled
EncryptDNS:     Disabled
CacheDNSSEC:    Disabled
ValidateDNSRep: Disabled
CheckUnsDNSRep: Disabled
LocalDNS:       Enabled (is this correct?)
NoDNSRebind:    Enabled
QueryDNSStrict: Enabled
RequestorMAC:   Disabled
```

And no additional options

**Linux Home Server** (192.168.1.20):

`/etc/hostname`

```
S001
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost S001
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 192.168.1.20
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

I'm pretty new to setting up DNS in general. Does anything look off? Do you have any idea why the DNS isn't getting hit, or what the `No internal type for both IPv4/v6` error means?

**UPDATE**: I've installed `dig` on my Windows client for additional info, and hitting the dns via 192.168.1.1 gave me a valid query of status `NOERROR`, but with no `ANSWER SECTION` and no `A` records.

I hardcoded the dns addresses on my client's NIC to 192.168.1.20, and got this from a `dig` sample query to one of my dns names:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.14.0 <<>> REDACTED
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60944
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: f57ba5147d707a93c2a4328f5c9ae973c0bd569d9d31e87a (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;REDACTED                               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
REDACTED                38400   IN      CNAME   REDACTED
REDACTED                38400   IN      A       192.168.1.20

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
REDACTED                38400   IN      NS      localhost.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
localhost.              604800  IN      A       127.0.0.1
localhost.              604800  IN      AAAA    ::1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.20#53(192.168.1.20)
;; WHEN: REDACTED
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 168
```

And I can get to webpages via the dns names. When going back to Automatic DNS settings, it breaks again. It looks very likely that the issue is something to do with the DD-WRT router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out the culprit was DNSMasq itself. After unchecking `Use DNSMasq for DHCP`, `Use DNSMasq for DNS`, and `DHCP-Authoritative` and then disabling DNSMasq, the DNS queries and site navigation started working again.

I'm not sure if there is a clean way to forward the queries via DNSMasq if someone wanted to do the same thing I'm doing but with DNSMasq enabled, but since I don't have a need for it I'm just going to leave it disabled.